# Currency Data Type (Microsoft SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server-2014, currency

How to use currency data type in SQL Server? I want my currency in MYR (Malaysian Ringgit) sign. Will it work the same as integer type, so that I can do calculation in it? Thank you!

Comment: What's the sign of MYR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Decimal` datatype for dealing with currency.

About the sign of any culture use `Format` function via passing the correct code of your selected culture:

**Examples:**

```
DECLARE @Price Decimal(21,6) =  1500.50

SELECT FORMAT(@Price,'c','en-US') AS 'CURRENCY IN US Culture'
SELECT FORMAT(@Price,'c','ar-EG') AS 'CURRENCY IN LE Egypt Culture'    
SELECT FORMAT(@Price,'c','ms-MY') AS 'CURRENCY IN Malaysia Culture'
```

**Result:-**

[image]

follow the next link for getting the [Table of Language Culture Names, Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Decimal` datatype for dealing with currency in SQL Server

```
SELECT FORMAT(price_amount,'c','ms-MY') AS 'CURRENCY IN Malaysia Culture'
```

Output

```
RM price_amount
```